# How can I perform a CoW copy but fallback to hardliking if the filesystem does not support it?

Tags: linux, bash, cp

As hardlinking has it downsides related to file permission requirements (across different users) I want to improve the logic used by some file copy operations and implement something like:

```
if cow_supported; then
    cp --reflink=auto src/ dst/
else
    cp -l src/ dst/
fi
```

This has to work in bash without requiring exotic too but common ones are accepted (rsync).

The priorities here are: speed first, disk space economy 2nd.  This is copying a cache which is unlikely to receive many updates after copy.

I think we can probably assume that src and dest are on the same partition.

I need to assure that these operations work on: Fedora/RHEL/CentOS, Debian/Ubuntu inside or outside containers, baremetals or vms.--- this means a high range of possible filesystems to consider: xfs, ext3/4, btrfs, overlayfs,...

Comment: What happens if you use `--reflink=auto` on a system where this isn't supported? Can you suggest an easy way to set up a system where we can repro this?

Comment: @tripleee when cow is not supporred ``--reflink=auto`` mode copies the files and others commented that this is worse than using the old hardlinking approach (as it would require considerably more time and disk space). Is like I am looking for a new copy strategy that is not supported by current cp.

Comment: Doesn't  `cp --reflink=always || cp -l` do what you want then?

Comment: hmmm... with some extra hiding of errors this could work and tbh it looks very clean. I need to run some testing code for it to see how it behaves in various scenarios as is important to avoid any confusing messages on the console: on build logs we clearly do not want to see redherrings, we already have enough.